# Signing out of ADFS 3.0 in ASP.net MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, adfs3.0

In my scenario I have a web app that connects to a remote ADFS server. Signing in works fine, as well as passing the correct LDAP attributes. What isn't working is signing out.

For signing out I was using the following lines which of course work but only as a measure of deleting web app cookies i.e. FedAuth cookies and not the STS ones.

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut();
FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.DeleteSessionTokenCookie();
```

My question is: What does one have to do to delete the STS cookies as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the:

WSFederationAuthenticationModule.FederatedSignOut Method

This sends a wsignout1.0 which tells the STS to delete cookies.

(Assuming WS-Fed of course).